# Reduce distance between ticklabels in pgfplots barplot

Tags: pgfplots

I have problem with my code in Tikz. I need smaller spaces bettwen names at line x.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb] 
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        xlabel = Strany,
        xmin = 0.5,
        xmax = 10.5,
        ymin = 0,
        ymax = 25,
        axis x line* = bottom,
        axis y line* = left,
        ylabel= Procenta,
        width= 2.8\textwidth,
        height = 0.6\textwidth,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        bar width = 2mm,
        xticklabels = \empty,
        extra x ticks = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7},
        extra x tick labels = {ČSSD,ANO,KSČM,TOP,Ods,Úsvit,KDU-ČSL},
        ]
        \addplot+[mark=none, orange, very thick] coordinates {
            (1,20)
        };
        \addplot+[mark=none, blue, very thick] coordinates {
            (2,19)
        };
        \addplot+[mark=none, purple, very thick] coordinates {
            (3,15)
        };
        \addplot+[mark=none, blue, very thick] coordinates {
            (4,12)
        };
        \addplot+[mark=none, green, very thick] coordinates {
            (5,8)
        };
        \addplot+[mark=none, yellow, very thick] coordinates {
            (6,7)
        };
        \addplot+[mark=none, yellow, very thick] coordinates {
            (7,7)
        };
    \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[Volby do Poslanecké sněmovny 2014]{Volby do Poslanecké sněmovny         2014}
\label{fig:new_ev}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you complete your code so we can compile it? Thanks.

Comment: I think  `width= 2.8\textwidth` may be problamatic. Try `width= \textwidth` instead.  Also, please note that while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: I complete it. Delete 2.8 cant help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space between the bars is mainly determined by the width of the axis, so naturally removing the `2.8` before `\textwidth` will help. However, there is a another problem:

When you use `\begin{axis}[ybar,...]` the idea is that each `\addplot` creates one bar at each `x` coordinate. Take this example from the manual:

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
ybar,
bar width=7pt,
]
\addplot
coordinates {(1930,50e6) (1940,33e6)
(1950,40e6) (1960,50e6) (1970,70e6)};

\addplot
coordinates {(1930,38e6) (1940,42e6)
(1950,43e6) (1960,45e6) (1970,65e6)};
\addplot
coordinates {(1930,15e6) (1940,12e6)
(1950,13e6) (1960,25e6) (1970,35e6)};

\legend{Far,Near,Here,Annot}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This generates three bars on each x-coordinate, one from each `\addplot`, shifted a bit so there is no overlap:

[image]

The point is that when you have multiple `\addplot`s in your `axis`, they will be shifted a bit relative to the x-coordinate, to make room for bars from the other `\addplot`s. So when you have seven `\addplot`s, `pgfplots` will make room for seven bars at each x-coordinate. Hence, the first bar is placed far left of the tick, the second one a bit closer and so on, with the last bar far right of the tick.

What you should do is either

1. use just one `\addplot`, or
2. move the `ybar` to the `\addplot` options.

With the first option all the bars will have the same colour, but I think that is just as well in this case. Both are demonstrated in the code below.

Below you will note that I used `symbolic x coords`, removed `xmin`/`xmax`, and added `xticklabel style={font=\vphantom{Ú}}`. The latter makes all the ticklabels the same height, so they're properly aligned. I also reduced the width to `0.95\textwidth`, and increased the `bar width` a bit.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        xlabel = Strany,
        ymin = 0,
        ymax = 25,
        axis x line* = bottom,
        axis y line* = left,
        ylabel= Procenta,
        width= 0.95\textwidth,
        height = 0.6\textwidth,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        bar width = 5mm,
        symbolic x coords = {ČSSD,ANO,KSČM,TOP,Ods,Úsvit,KDU-ČSL},
        xticklabel style={font=\vphantom{Ú}}
        ]
        \addplot coordinates {
            (ČSSD,20) (ANO,19) (KSČM,15) (TOP,12) (Ods,8) (Úsvit,7) (KDU-ČSL,7)
        };
    \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[Volby do Poslanecké sněmovny 2014]{Volby do Poslanecké sněmovny 2014}
\label{fig:new_ev}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[
        no markers,
        xlabel = Strany,
        ymin = 0,
        ymax = 25,
        axis x line* = bottom,
        axis y line* = left,
        ylabel= Procenta,
        width= 0.95\textwidth,
        height = 0.6\textwidth,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        bar width = 5mm,
        symbolic x coords = {ČSSD,ANO,KSČM,TOP,Ods,Úsvit,KDU-ČSL},
        xticklabel style={font=\vphantom{Ú}}
        ]
        \addplot+[ybar, fill, orange] coordinates {
            (ČSSD,20)
        };
        \addplot+[ybar, fill, blue] coordinates {
            (ANO,19)
        };
        \addplot+[ybar, fill, purple] coordinates {
            (KSČM,15)
        };
        \addplot+[ybar, fill, blue] coordinates {
            (TOP,12)
        };
        \addplot+[ybar, fill, green] coordinates {
            (Ods,8)
        };
        \addplot+[ybar, fill, yellow] coordinates {
            (Úsvit,7)
        };
        \addplot+[ybar, fill, yellow] coordinates {
            (KDU-ČSL,7)
        };
    \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[Volby do Poslanecké sněmovny 2014]{Volby do Poslanecké sněmovny 2014}
\label{fig:new_ev}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```